# Getting inbox rules for all mailboxes which set to forward redirect to

Tags: powershell

I'd looking for a script to query the entire Org (all mailboxes), find the Inbox rule(s) where it's set to forward, redirect or forward as attachment to external address and output to a file with userID, rule name and external recipient smtp.

I have written so far something like that.

Specicially , I am getting very strange output for Ruledescription  and RedirectTo.  How can we solve this ?

Script :

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited  |
foreach {
    Write-Verbose "Checking $($_.alias)..." -Verbose
    $inboxrule = get-inboxrule -Mailbox $_.alias  
    if ($inboxrule) {
        foreach($rule in $inboxrule){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Mailbox         = $_.alias
            Rulename        = $rule.name
            Rulepriority    = $rule.priority
            Ruledescription = $rule.description
            ForwardTo       = $rule.ForwardTo
            ForwardAsAttachmentTo = $rule.ForwardAsAttachmentTo
            RedirectTo = $rule.RedirectTo
            DeleteMessage = $rule.DeleteMessage
        }
    }
    }
} | 
Export-csv "C:\temp\inbox_ruleexport.csv" -NoTypeInformation -encoding UTF8
```

Output :

```
"Mailbox","Rulename","Rulepriority","Ruledescription","ForwardTo","ForwardAsAttachmentTo","RedirectTo","DeleteMessage"
"user","[all forwarding]","1","Take the following actions:
    redirect the message to 'user@contoso.com'
    and stop processing more rules on this message
",,,"Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.Management.ADRecipientOrAddress[]","False"
```

LAST UPDATE:

```
Name                  : User02
Identity              : contoso.local/IT/John\18197132819417792513
ForwardTo             : {"User02@hotmail.com" [SMTP:User02@hotmail.com]}
ForwardAsAttachmentTo : 
RedirectTo            : 
DeleteMessage         : False
Description           : If the message:
                            the message was received from 'John'
                        Take the following actions:
                            forward the message to 'User02@hotmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Ruledescription` is ok. It is exactly the description that is seen in Outlook. It's just not as pretty and contains those line breaks. You can remove them with

```
Ruledescription = $rule.description -replace [Environment]::NewLine , ''
```

`RedirectTo` returns an array of type `ADRecipientOrAddress[]`, and Powershell has trouble converting it to a string. However, it contains useful information. You only want the rules that forward externally, so you can filter if the `RoutingType` of these objects contains `SMTP` before creating the `[PSCustomObject]`:

```
$rule.ForwardTo.RoutingType -contains `SMTP`.
```

The same is true for `ForwardAsAttachmentTo` and `RedirectTo`.
Now we only want the `Address` of `ADRecipientOrAddress[]`. So we select only this one:

```
ForwardTo = $rule.ForwardTo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Address
```

On top of that, there can be multiple addresses per object, since it is an array. Here we apply a little trick and use them directly in a string:

```
ForwardTo = "$($rule.ForwardTo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Address)"
```

Once you've done all that, your CSV file should look fine.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited  |
foreach {
    Write-Verbose "Checking $($_.alias)..." -Verbose
    $inboxrule = get-inboxrule -Mailbox $_.alias  
    if ($inboxrule) {
        foreach($rule in $inboxrule){
        if ($rule.ForwardTo.RoutingType -contains 'SMTP'-or $rule.ForwardAsAttachmentTo.RoutingType -contains 'SMTP'-or $rule.RedirectTo.RoutingType -contains 'SMTP' ){
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Mailbox         = $_.alias
                Rulename        = $rule.name
                Rulepriority    = $rule.priority
                Ruledescription = $rule.description -replace [environment]::NewLine , ''
                ForwardTo       = "$($rule.ForwardTo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Address)"
                ForwardAsAttachmentTo = "$($rule.ForwardAsAttachmentTo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Address)"
                RedirectTo = "$($rule.RedirectTo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Address)"
                DeleteMessage = $rule.DeleteMessage
            }
        }

    }
    }
}
```